# 2’s complement checksum

Tags: javascript, math, checksum, addition

I am trying to implement a [protocol](https://www.grassvalley.com/docs/Manuals/sam/Protocols%20and%20MIBs/Router%20Control%20Protocols%20SW-P-88%20Issue%204b.pdf) which use a certain checksum calculation I am unable to reproduce.

The specification says the checksum should be "7 bit, 2’s complement sum of command and message field
(m.s.b. = 0)".

Which according to me should be possible to calculate with:

```
const data = [0x04, 0x00, 0x10, 0x10, 0x18, 0x57, 0x05]
let sum = 0x00
for (let value of data) {
  sum += value
}
const chk = 256 - sum // OR (~sum + 1) & 0xFF

console.log('0x' + chk.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'))
```

See, https://repl.it/repls/UntidySpotlessInternalcommand.

However, the result I get is 0x68, while the example I have says it should be 0x78.

Am I misunderstanding something in terms of calculating 2's complement sum?

The example is taken from a successfully executed command which is seen in a console window provided by the manufacturer.

[image: Example]

Breaks down into:

```
SOM   10 02
CMD   04 (CONNECTED)
DATA  00 10 10 18 57
BTC   05
CHK   78
EOM   10 03
```

Comment: I have no idea, but to help you get an answer, to be clear: both ways you show in your code don't work?

Comment: Nope, neither work.

Comment: Where are you getting the example data from that says the checksum should be 0x78? Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @ToddChaffee updated question

Comment: I don't know how they got to 0x78 either, but notice that it says *7 bit*. Add `& 0x7F` somewhere.

Comment: @ronag Could you follow up and let us know what you find out about this? I'm curious what it turns out to be.

Answer (score 3):

You should contact the manufacturer. Even using a programming calculator and making sure to use only 7 bits, the checksum comes out to 0x68. I'm not entirely sure your calculation is correct as per another comment it might not be 7 bit. But the sum of the numbers you provided is a 7 bit number anyway, so in the example you gave it shouldn't matter. It might matter for other data though. But definitely contact the company because the correct checksum does seem to be 0x68.